# ¿Cómo decir "Cage free eggs" en español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, comida, solicitud-de-término

Tengo a mi padre de visita unos días. El otro día fuimos a hacer la compra juntos y para elegir huevos le quise decir que cogiésemos los "Cage free eggs", y no supe encontrar las palabras para traducirlo.

Los compraba también en España, cuando vivía ahí, pero no me acuerdo de cómo los llamaban o qué ponía exactamente en la etiqueta. Sólo pude explicar que son huevos que ponen gallinas que están "en libertad" o más bien, que no viven encerradas en jaulas minúsculas con luces artificiales 24 horas al día para que estén poniendo huevos constantemente.

Supongo que "en libertad" no es del todo correcto, ya que no son gallinas "salvajes" y "que no viven en jaulas diminutas" no creo que sea una buena etiqueta para poner en la huevera.

¿Cómo se traduce "cage free eggs" en español?

Comment: Nunca había escuchado ese término, pero se me ocurre "huevos de gallinas no enjauladas". No lo pongo como respuesta ya que es un mero intento de traducción y no tengo referencias que lo respalden.

Comment: En conversación con tu papá, quizás podrías inventar algo sencillo como "huevos bío".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depende un poco.  Según [este artículo](http://www.abc.es/sociedad/20131011/abci-huevos-ecologicos-jaulas-diferencian-201310101250.html), hay tres designaciones en España.

Si la gallina no está enjaulada, pero tampoco está al aire libre, se llaman **huevos de suelo**.

Y si están libres (ni jaula ni nave ni nada), se llaman **huevos camperos**.

Los huevos camperos cuyas gallinas solo comían comida ecológica se pueden llamar **huevos ecológicos**.

En todo caso, creo que es más común asociar estos términos a la gallina en vez de al huevo: *huevos de gallinas criadas en el suelo*, o *de gallinas camperas*.

Answer (score 8):

Para complementar la respuesta de Guifa, añado una descripción de los códigos de los huevos:

[image]

Y como se puede ver, hay 4 tipos:

**Granjas de gallinas en jaulas**: Viven en jaulas diseñadas especialmente para facilitar la recogida de los huevos, evitando que se ensucien con estiércol, tienen acceso al agua y a una alimentación equilibrada a base de pienso. Estas instalaciones facilitan el control sanitario y la limpieza. Es el sistema más habitual en España.

**Granjas de gallinas en suelo**: Se mueven libremente dentro de una nave, en la que tienen comida, agua, ponederos y zonas de descanso.

**Granjas de gallinas camperas**: Además de una nave como el de las gallinas en suelo, tienen corrales al aire libre donde salen a picotear, escarbar y darse baños de arena.

**Granjas de gallinas ecológicas**: Las instalaciones son similares a las granjas camperas, pero las gallinas se alimentan con pienso que procede de la agricultura ecológica y tienen que cumplir las normas específicas de esta producción.

Tú buscas unos de los 3 últimos.

Answer (score 1):

Acá en Chile se les conoce como "°huevos de gallinas felices". Es medio raro el término pero así les dicen acá.

Answer (score -1):

En México verás huevos de **libre pastoreo** y de **gallina libre**.

Véanse http://www.airesdecampo.com/nuestros-productos/abarrotes/huevo/ y http://bachoco.com.mx/productos/huevoblancogallinalibre/99-huevo-blanco-gallina-libre-cage-free respectivamente.